# What are some tactics for killing skeletron prime? (terrarria iOS)

Tags: terraria-mobile

Here is my issue: the game keeps on giving me the message "The air is getting cold around you". Then Skeletron Prime awakens, and its always when I'm underground! But, it gives me time to get my equipment ready. Any good tips / Armor and Weapons I should use?

[image]

Comment: If you only have Bee armor, no wonder you are getting killed fast. Skeletron Prime is one of the toughest bosses in the entire game. You need ATLEAST Adamanite or Hallow equipment to even think to fight him. This also bring up the topic of your question. Could you give us more details on your tactics and equipment. It is hard to judge what you should change just by seeing a picture of your character in the dark. We can't help you just based on this.

Comment: Though peeking at your hotbar does show your equipment is too weak to even budge his HP. I suggest crafting a Megashark with about 1000 Cursed bullets. Melee is very difficult against him. Also, wings and a special designed arena could help... (though this may be impossible if you can't avoid him. You could run towards the bottom of the world then teleport up top to shake him and give yourself time to prepare.) Finally, if you can, farm the Destroyer and Twins for Hallowed items BEFORE trying to take on Skeletron.

Comment: @TheMattbat999 That sounds like a good answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here are some suggestions that I have that will help: (this is what I did to kill it)

1. Designed Arena

Here is a diagram of what you could use ( "=" are platforms and "×" is your solid ground where to put Campfires, and Heart and Mana statues rigged to a timer)

=======

×××××××

This is where you will need wings: simply fly around from the platforms and back. The distance doesn't matter, as long as you can reach the row of platforms.

2. Weapons and Armor

Megashark with ATLEAST 1000 Cursed bullets.

Best to have Hallowed armor. You can get hallowed bars from The Destroyer and Twins to make said armor.

3. Items and Accessories

Have plenty of Greater healing potions. Any potions to boost defense and ranged damage will help.

Wings and possibly a Ranger Emblem will help. Make sure all of your accessories have a modifier to boost defense.

4. The fight

Simply fly in between the platforms and the ground, dodging him and continuously shooting at his head. Don't focus on the arms. This fight will take a while, but, with luck, if possible a friend, you will kill it. Don't bother with a respawn point because he disappears as soon as you die, no matter what.